# Ruby Proc Syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, proc-object

An answer to a question I posed yesterday on here was the following piece of Ruby code:

```
def overlap?(r1,r2)
  r1.include?(r2.begin) || r2.include?(r1.begin)
end

def any_overlap?(ranges)
  ranges.sort_by(&:begin).each_cons(2).any? do |r1,r2|
  overlap?(r1, r2)
  end
end
```

I get `each_cons`, but what's the strange `&:begin` notation?  Save me from syntax hell!

Thanks!

Comment: This more or less a duplicate of [Understanding `[ClassOne, ClassTwo].each(&:my_method)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/99318/), [What does `map(&:name)` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1217088/), [What exactly is is this in ruby: `&:capitalize`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1792683/), [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1961030/), [Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2096975/), [What is this `&:last` Ruby Construct Called?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2211751/), ...

Comment: ... [What do you call the `&:` operator in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2259775/), [What does `map(&:name)` do in this Ruby code?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2388337/), [What are `:+` and `&+` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2697024/) and [`&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3888044/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you prefix the last argument of a call with `&` you are making clear that you are sending a block and not a *normal* argument. Ok, in `method(&:something)`, `:something` is a symbol, not a *proc*, so Ruby automatically calls the method `to_proc` to get a real block. And Rails guys (and now also vanilla Ruby) cleverly defined it as:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

That's why you can do:

```
>> [1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s) # instead of [1, 2, 3].map { |n| n.to_s }
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

[edit] Note: when you realize that this construction is no syntatic sugar but generic infrastructure that Ruby provides, nothing stops you from implementing your own `to_proc` for other classes. Never felt limited because `&:method` allowed no arguments?

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(*(self + args)) }
  end
end

>> ["1", "F", "FF"].map(&[:to_i, 16])
=> [1, 15, 255]
```

Answer (score 2):

`my_method(&some_value)` means to invoke `my_method`, passing `some_value` in the special argument slot, the proc-slot, usually reserved for passing do-notation blocks.

```
my_block = lambda { puts "hello" }
(1..3).each(&my_block)
```

Any object which is a `Proc` or which responds to `to_proc` is permitted to be passed in the proc-slot. If you pass in an object which is not a `Proc` but which responds to `to_proc`, then Ruby will call `to_proc` on the object for you and pass the result into the method.

The implementation of `Symbol#to_proc` is to return a proc which, when passed an argument, sends that argument the message that is the symbol itself. For example, `:hello.to_proc.call(my_obj)` will end up doing `my_obj.send :hello`.

So `my_array.each(&:hello)` passes `:hello` to `each` in the proc-slot (where a block would normally passed, if you used the do-notation to make a block). `:hello.to_proc.call(my_array[0])` ends up being `my_array[0].send :hello`, and the same for all subsequent indexes of `my_array`.

Answer (score 1):

it equals:

```
ranges.sort_by{|r| r.begin}
```

Comment: sorry, @mbm. The reason is & will invoke the to_proc method.